# labeling rows in dataframe, based on dynamic conditions

Tags: python, pandas

i need some help with labeling data inside dataframe, based on dynamic conditions.
I have a dataframe

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'John', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane','Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'John'],
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
    'age': [30, 30, 25, 25, 25, 30, 45, 15, 30],
    'group': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'product_type': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'quantity': [10, 15, 10, 10, 15, 30, 30, 10, 10]
})
df3['agemore'] = (df3['age'] > 20)
df3
```

So i need to take first person with id=1 and group =0 and  label him with group=1 (on all of his rows).
This person placed on 3 rows (indexes 0, 1, 8) and has agemore=True, product_type = 1, 1, 2 and quantity = 10, 15, 10.

Condition for looking matched persons are based on product_type,quantity, agemore columns.
the first taken person slice:

```
df6=df3.loc[lambda df: (df['id'] ==1) &(df['product_type'] ==1), :] 
df6
```

i need to take agemore = True, product_type = 1 (with is on two rows) and quantity of product of this type(10,15) for conditions.
and i will look for persons with has agemore = True, product_type = 2(two, its cross column search) (with is on two rows) and quantity of product_type = 2 (10,15) for conditions. The matched person has id 2. i must put this person in group 1 as well.

Then take next person with lowest id and group=0, take his conditions, look for similar, group them together etc

The output i would like to have

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'John', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane','Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'John'],
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
    'age': [30, 30, 25, 25, 25, 30, 45, 15, 30],
    'group': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1],
    'product_type': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'quantity': [10, 15, 10, 10, 15, 30, 30, 10, 10]
})


df4
```

set2

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'John', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane','Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'John'],
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
    'age': [30, 30, 25, 25, 25, 30, 45, 15, 3],
    'group': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'product_type': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    'quantity': [10, 15, 10, 10, 15, 30, 30, 10, 10]
})
data['agemore'] = (data['age'] > 20)
```

Comment: Can you include your expected output, and inline annotation as for why each label is applied to the individual? It's hard to follow the logic written in long-form paragraphs.

Comment: Don't forget to include _annotations_ __why__ each id was assigned to each individual _per row_ as the long-form logic is not clear.

Comment: Hello Henry, too bad , i cant write directly to you.    in Short, i take first person with lowest id and no group. df6=df3.loc[lambda df: (df['id'] ==1), :] then i need to take only  [quantity =10 for product_type=1, , agemore= True] as condition. and will look for all other persons with [product_type=2, quantity =10, agemore= True].

Comment: At start i had two dataframes with persons and product types and quantities, but later i used left_join_df= pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='left'), to create one single df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rm1991, thanks for clarifying your question.

From the information provided, I gathered that you are trying to group customers by their behavior and age group. I can also infer that the IDs are assigned to customers when they first make a transaction with you, which means that the higher the ID value, the newer the customer is to the company.

If this is the case, I would suggest you use an unsupervised learning method to cluster the data points by their similarity regarding the product type, quantity purchased, and age group. Have a look at [the SKLearn suite of clustering algorithms](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) for further information.

**NB: upon further clarification from rm1991, it seems that product_type is not a "clustering" criteria.**

I have replicated your output using only Pandas logic within a loop, as you can see below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['John', 'John', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane','Marry', 'Victoria', 'Gabriel', 'John'],
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1],
    'age': [30, 30, 25, 25, 25, 30, 45, 15, 30],
    'group': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'product_type': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'quantity': [10, 15, 10, 10, 15, 30, 30, 10, 10]
})
data['agemore'] = (data['age'] > 20)

group_val = 0

for id in data['id'].unique():
    age_param = list(set([age_bool for age_bool in data.loc[data['id'] == id, 'agemore']]))
    # Product type removed as per latest requirements
    # product_type_param = list(set([prod_type for prod_type in data.loc[data['id'] == id, 'product_type']]))
    quantity_param = list(set([qty for qty in data.loc[data['id'] == id, 'quantity']]))
            
    if data.loc[(data['id'] == id)
                & (data['group']==0), :].shape[0] > 0:
        group_val += 1

    data.loc[(data['group'] == 0)
         & (data['agemore'].isin(age_param))
         # Product_type removed as per latest requirements
         # & (data['product_type'].isin(product_type_param))
         & (data['quantity'].isin(quantity_param)), 'group'] = group_val
```

*Now* the output **does** match what you've posted earlier:

```
      first_name  id  age  group  product_type  quantity  agemore
0       John   1   30      1             1        10     True
1       John   1   30      1             1        15     True
2       Jane   2   25      1             2        10     True
3       Jane   2   25      1             1        10     True
4       Jane   2   25      1             2        15     True
5      Marry   3   30      2             1        30     True
6   Victoria   4   45      2             2        30     True
7    Gabriel   5   15      3             1        10    False
8       John   1   30      1             2        10     True
```

<s>It remains unclear to me why Victoria, with ID = 4, would be assigned to the same group as Marry (ID = 3), given that they have not purchased the same product_type.</s>

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: IDs and product_type need to split data... ill take first person with id and product_type=1... it will have ONLY two rows IN Two Columns quantity and agemore  for future comparing (1-10, True and 2 -15, True).. The compared data sliced on conditions ID and product_type=2 (two)

Comment: mary ID=3, and product_type =1, give as quantity 30, agemore =true, vitoria ID=4, and product_type =2, give as quantity 30, agemore =true, so they are in same group

Comment: that is exactly, what i was looking for, thank you

Comment: hello i checked with another set where john and jane must not be in one group... when last john have =false... and resultsis not correct.. can you check it please